# How to cancel UIScrollView bounce animation after dragging?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

How to cancel UIScrollView bounce animation after dragging? ( NOT DISABLE BOUNCE )

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

some kind effect like dragRefresh? If it is, you should set your scrollView contentInset at scrollView end drag delegate method.

Answer (score 0):

set the content offset in the scrollView delegate method `scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity:targetContentOffset:`

```
- (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset;
{
  scrollView.contentOffset = //.. content offset of where you want it to stop, use the current offset if you want it to stay where it is.
}
```

Your question is vague and doesn't give me much to go on to provide a better answer, hope this is of help.

Answer (score -1):

```
[scrollView setContentOffset:scrollView.contentOffset animated:NO];
```

NOTE: You must use the animated version of the function - not the version without the animated flag.